# how to color a drawing in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to color a heart. I push shift button on keyboard and click on the heart and choose the color from color panel. but nothing happens. Or just some parts of heart are colored. Can anybody help me find the way to color it completely? Thanks.

Comment: can you edit your post to add some screen shots of what your heart looks like now?

Comment: Thanks. It worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know your current X button is Fill or Stroke. You can change it by pressed X button. If you say "some parts of heart are colored" maybe the active X is Stroke. You can change it to Fill for filling your heart color.
Second, try to check your document color preview obtion, make sure it's set to RGB or CMYK preview (not Greyscale). And you can see the picture below. Hope it's help. [image]